# Can I use a UPS in front of my A/C heat pump, to reduce surges in the house?

Tags: electrical, heat-pump

Hopefully this is on-topic here. I'm open if I should as on another SE site.

We have an air conditioner heat pump outside, typical to most homes with one. When it kicks on, many of the lights dim for a split second.

Assuming it is not an old unit and it has a problem (maybe it is?) - I am wondering if I can put a UPS (battery-backed power supply) between it and its breaker on the panel. I admittedly don't know if this meets local code.

I would like to first understand if it's a viable solution for home line levels. I'd also like to understand how I should think about its impacts on the lifetime / 'MTFB' of the UPS I'd use.

I understand there will be lots that is specific to the sizing of the heat pump (its load), and maybe other factors. I'm happy to update this question with other needed details.

Also, I'm open if there's a better way, altogether, to approach this besides a UPS.  (someone mentioned an "inrush current limiter")

Comment: There are "soft start" kits for compressors that limit the instantaneous current spikes, that might improve this. However, the are reports that these might not be suitable for compressors in some older condensing units.

Comment: How old is the unit? If you can give us a model number we might be able to tell you if there's a soft start kit available.

Answer (score 3):

Most homes have a heat pump outside, but it's a plain old 7-13 SEER non-reversible "air conditioner" with bang-bang controls. Meaning at opportune times it goes "SKREEhrmmmmmmmmmmm" and at another opportune time it goes "mmmmSHUCka" and falls silent.  Yes, that latter event generates one heck of a surge.

And you're looking for a one-way valve for AC that will trap the surge at the A/C.

So, a UPS will work if you choose the relatively rare type that works the way you think UPS's work - the "online" type that delivers AC power to a DC bus then inverts to make local AC.

However, having the UPS output spun up all the time would be dumb. There is a 24V signal from the thermostat on Y/C which tells the air conditioner to spin up. So why not redirect that to the UPS to have it only output when Y/C are energized?

Well now we have all the hardware needed for a VFD. So now the inverter can spool down frequency to soft-stop the motor, and surges largely go away.

So now we ask "since we have a VFD, why not drive the heat pump at variable speed for the efficiency gains?"  And here we are at Asian style efficient heat pumps, which are also two-way (they heat).

And dollar for dollar rather than homebrew hacking this advanced feature-set onto That 70’s air conditioning tech, probably better to go with the modern Asian style unit.

Answer (score 2):

Not a good idea. If it cycles every startup, you'll ruin it pretty quickly. And it won't help the rest of the house.

In theory a double conversion UPS for everything else would help, but that would get very expensive. Standard consumer UPSes are standby systems and would help some but cycle every AC startup and wear out quickly.

You've either got a problem with your AC or your service is just too small.